# Words with Friends some opponents’ letters in tile bag others aren’t

Tags: words-with-friends

Against some opponents no matter how many games I am playing their tiles don’t appear in the tile bag, nor mine in theirs, although when we started they did. Other opponents’ tiles do appear. Why is this? Would actually prefer if the former were the case for all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be a bug in WWF. It's my opinion that their tiles should appear in the bag. If they didn't then their opponent could figure it out using simple match or some kind of cheat app, allowing them to strategize around it.

This wouldn't be the first WWF bug that gives an advantage to one player of the other. At one time there were older versions of the game that allowed a different word list than the current version on the App Store.

Comment: Agree but when there are no tiles left to take the bag normally shows opponent’s letters so easy to strategise. If they weren’t there then it would,as you say, require checking the numbers of each letter already played to find out what the opponent has left making it more difficult to ‘cheat’.